# Arcpy - How I can i make my Select By Location work?

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy

When trying to do a Select By Location, the same error keeps appearing :

arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: Failed to execute. Parameters are not valid.
ERROR 000368: Invalid input data.
Failed to execute (SelectLayerByLocation).

´´´

## 3. Calculate the points that are out of the buffer and treat them, relocating them or considering them trash (Select Layer By Location - points that do not intersect the buffer)

arcpy.env.workspace = "D:/Model/output_files"

sinistros = "ETRS89_Pontos_Sinistros.shp"
buffer = "buffer_freguesiasPorto_200.shp"

Fora_do_buffer = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(sinistros,'INTERSECT',buffer,'','SWITCH_SELECTION','')

´´´

I am expecting for the select by location to select all the points that do not intersect the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the parameter for selection_type is not used for what you are expecting. If selection type is set to 'SWITCH_SELECTION', already selected records in the input layer will be switched. What I think you're after instead is the invert_spatial_relationship parameter (see the ESRI documentation: https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/select-layer-by-location.htm).

Secondly, you may need to make your layers feature layers first before running Select By Location. For example (in ArcGIS for Desktop):

```py
sinistors = "D:/Model/output_files/ETRS89_Pontos_Sinistros.shp"
buffer = "D:/Model/output_files/buffer_freguesiasPorto_200.shp"

sinistros_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(sinistros, "sinistros")
buffer_layer = arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(buffer, "buffer")

fora_do_buffer = arcpy.SelectLayerByLocation_management(
    sinistros_layer,
    "INTERSECT", 
    buffer_layer,
    invert_spatial_relationship="INVERT"
)
```